# Visual Studio community 2017, disable restore when .net core csproj changes

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, csproj

Is is possible to disable the auto restore feature when you save a csproj file for a dot net core project in visual studio community 2017?

Comment: If you are not used to that, switch to Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Unfortunately that brings a whole other set of problems, especially when you are working in a Visual Studio shop

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Because it often fails when the command line version works. Because "run on save" functionality is something which disrupts my workflow. Because it slows down the dev environment.